# Before Mongo 3.2 which method was used to find

Tags: mongodb, go, backwards-compatibility, mgo

I have an installation of Mongo v3.0.15 and I cannot execute the find command from my application. I need to build this with backward compatibility, so, which command was used instead of find for previous versions of Mongo 3.2?
The current error that I receive from Mongo is:

```
find command not yet implemented
```

**mongo driver:** gopkg.in/mgo.v2
Then am trying to retrieve records using:

```
s.session.DB("").Run(rawQuery, &queryResult)
```

Comment: OP_QUERY I believe.

Comment: Please include what driver you're using. Post a [mcve].

Comment: @icza done, however it seems to be indifferent as its a raw query and the error comes from mongo directly because it doesn't support the find method

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova And what import path do you use? `mgo` has multiple forks.

Comment: @icza only "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova That has long become unmaintained, and the community fork [`github.com/globalsign/mgo`](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo) is in much better shape. It has identical API. Can you change your import and see if it works with `github.com/globalsign/mgo`?

Comment: @icza ouch!! no, its a big application in production :S

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova You don't have to try it in production. "Spin up" a MongoDB 3.0 locally and try it there.